# generating list for joint distribution

Tags: python, list, dynamically-generated

I'm pretty sure this is an easy problem but I am completely blacking out on how to fix this.  I am trying to work my way through the PGM class on coursera and it starts of with joint probability distribution.  So I am trying to generate a list of all possible distributions given n variables, where each variable can take on some discrete value between 0...z

so for instance say we have 3 variables, and each can take on values of just 0 and 1 I want to generate this:

```
[[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0]]
```

I am working in python I am drawing a blank on how to dynamically generate this.

Comment: Looks like you need [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer list comprehension:

```
[[a, b, c] for a in range(2) for b in range(2) for c in range(2)]
```

And I forgot to mention that you can use pprint to get the effect you want:

```
>>> import pprint  
>>> pprint.pprint([[a, b, c] for a in range(2) for b in range(2) for c in range(2)])  
[[0, 0, 0],  
 [0, 0, 1],  
 [0, 1, 0],  
 [0, 1, 1],  
 [1, 0, 0],  
 [1, 0, 1],  
 [1, 1, 0],  
 [1, 1, 1]]  
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want the Cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product
for x in product([0,1], [0,1], [0,1]):
    print x
```

> [0, 0, 0]
>   [0, 0, 1]
>   [0, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1]
>   [1, 0, 0]
>   [1, 0, 1]
>   [1, 1, 0]
>   [1, 1, 1]

Comment: No need to create 3 identical lists, `product` has the keyword argument `repeat` for this.

Comment: Good point @Lev.  I wasn't sure if all the variables in the question would take on the exact same values (seems like [0,1] was just a simplified example) so I listed them out in my response. if they do all have the same domain, follow Lev's suggestion and DRY.

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement over Nathan's method:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```